# How to verify a number in twilio account?

Tags: wordpress, twilio-click-to-call

I Am new to twilio. I am not able to verify a number however I have funds in my account and using the plug-in ACT Click2Call. Can any one help me to verify the number over there?So that I can add the outgoing numbers to the plug-in settings?